# File Builder - how to skip fileupload field if it's empty. "Call to a member function guessExtension() on null" error

Tags: symfony

m'm creating add/edit function and actually have problem with validation. I don't know how to skip fileupload file when i want to update data and i won't choose any file to upload. I just want to update other fields and leave added file as it is.

I always have guessExtension() on null if i dont upload anything.

I was trying to add if statement blocking code if "$extension = $file->guessExtension();" is empty but it doesn't work

```
/**
 * @Route("/panel/editarticle/{id}", name="edit_article")
 */
public function editArticle(Request $request, Article $article)
{

    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $form = $this->createForm(UploadFormType::class, $article);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted())
    {
        $file = $form->get('file')->getData();

            $extension = $file->guessExtension();
            if (!$extension) {

            } else {
                $fileName = sha1(random_bytes(14)).'.'.$file->$extension;

                $file->move(
                    $this->getParameter('videos_directory'),
                    $fileName
                );
            $article->setFile($fileName);
            }



        $entityManager->persist($article);
        $entityManager->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('article_list');
    }



    return $this->render('article/addpost.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'ArticleController',
        'article' => $article,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

I expect form to update successfuly even if i won't upload any file. In this case file uploaded before is still in database. For no i need to upload file to make my form work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, because you cant use the guessExtension() on null, this is a method of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File`

https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/File/File.php

So try this:

```
$file = $form->get('file')->getData();
if ($file) {
    $extension = $file->guessExtension();
    //etc ...
}
```

Or even better:

```
$file = $form->get('file')->getData();
if ($file instanceof File) {
    $extension = $file->guessExtension();
    //etc ...
}
```

But in the second case you need add a use statement to your class:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
```

... Anyway I'm not sure, is a best practice the $form->handleRequest($request) ... I never use it. May more secure, if you just render the form in a method, and in an another you validate the request first, and just after then create the entity... In this case you can get and validate the FileBag:

```
$files = $request->files;
if ($files instanceof FileBag and !empty ($files)) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        //surely a valid file
        $extension = $file->guessExtension();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Also necessary the use statement if you validate the `FileBag` with `instanceof`:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag;
```